# Wrong value on my autoComplementTextview

Tags: java, android, json, autocompletetextview

Hey guys is my first time using `autoComplementTextView` with `JSON`. Parser I am following this [tutorial](http://androidmapv2.blogspot.pt/2013/11/android-autocompletetextview-with.html) and I receive the roads on a list but when I click on a road imagine: "Road of stackoverflow" the output on  my `autoComplementTextView` is `{description= Road of stackoverflow}`

My code it's equals to the tutorial link.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109954727/Map/map13.zip

Comment: wrong tutorial: do it [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830) way

Comment: Psking your tutorial work but i need the url on google maps can you help me ? i  dont know what i need to input on  url string ?